# 'file --mime-type' vs 'mimetype' for php files

Tags: 12.04, php, mime-type

I'm trying to understand the difference between `file --mime-type` and `mimetype`.  They are giving me different results on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS for this simple php file.

```
<?php
  echo 'Hello world!';
?>
```

Now when I use mimetype and file to get the type of the file, I get:

```
$ mimetype -b test.php
application/x-php

$ file -b --mime-type test.php
test/x-php
```

This question (['file --mime-type' and 'mimetype' Commands Returning Different Results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279899/file-mime-type-and-mimetype-commands-returning-different-results)) says that `file` uses `/etc/mime.types` however:

```
$ grep php /etc/mime.types
application/x-httpd-php                         phtml pht php
application/x-httpd-php-source                  phps
application/x-httpd-php3                        php3
application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed           php3p
application/x-httpd-php4                        php4
application/x-httpd-php5                        php5
```

I'm most curious about why `file` sees it as a text file.  This is causing me problems in Rails as Ruby's MIME type also sees it as type application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/file.1.html) `file` doesn't use `/etc/mime.types` but the compiled definitions from `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc`, the  plain text definitions from `/etc/magic` and some other files.

You can get the source code for `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc` from the source code of the `file` package (have a look into the `magic/` subfolder).

If you want `file` to return `application/x-php` add the following to `/etc/magic`:

```
# PHP scripts
# Ulf Harnhammar <ulfh@update.uu.se>
0       search/1/c      =<?php                  PHP script text
!:mime  application/x-php
0       search/1        =<?\n                   PHP script text
!:mime  application/x-php
0       search/1        =<?\r                   PHP script text
!:mime  application/x-php
0       search/1/w      #!\ /usr/local/bin/php  PHP script text executable
!:mime  application/x-php
0       search/1/w      #!\ /usr/bin/php        PHP script text executable
!:mime  application/x-php
# Smarty compiled template, http://www.smarty.net/
# Elan Ruusamäe <glen@delfi.ee>
0       string  =<?php\ /*\ Smarty\ version     Smarty compiled template
>24     regex   [0-9.]+                         \b, version %s
!:mime  application/x-php
```