# Wrong MIME type and icon for a file in Nautilus

Tags: python, nautilus, qt5, mime-type, pyqt5

I am writing a GUI application in Python using PyQt5, with the main application named `main_app.py`. Despite being simply a Python script, and `file -i main_app.py` returning the correct MIME type `text/x-script.python`, the icon shown in the Nautilus is not that of a Python script and the MIME type reported by the "Properties" tab is `text/x-qml`.
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOglQ.png)

What is more puzzling is that, checking the `/etc/mime.types` file, there is no entry for `text/x-qml`! [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqmgq.png)

---

After playing around with the file a bit, I found out that this behavior depends really on the contents of the file. My first non-comment lines are

```
from custom_parser import Parser
import html
import json
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
```

If I remove all imports of PyQt5 libraries, Nautilus reports the correct icon and MIME type.

One last important (maybe) thing: I had [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) installed earlier on my PC (via `sudo apt install qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools`), but then removed it with `apt` in the same way. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 and Python 3.10.

---

Therefore, my question is: how can I prevent Nautilus from changing MIME type in this fashion? I don't need support for this extra `text/x-qml` MIME type, so it would be fine if I could just delete it from some configuration file.

Comment: Does `xdg-mime query default text/x-qml` return anything?

Comment: No. On top of things, `xdg-mime query filetype main_app.py` returns `text/x-qml` when the PyQt5 libraries are imported in the file, `text/x-python3` when not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @steeldriver 's comment and [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279899/file-mime-type-and-mimetype-commands-returning-different-results) I was able to find a solution. Evidently Qt Designer had not uninstalled itself correctly and left specifications for its `text/x-qml` MIME type in the file `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`:

```
<mime-type type="text/x-qml">
  <comment>Qt Markup Language file</comment>
  ...
  <magic priority="80">
    <match type="string" value="/bin/env qml" offset="2:16"/>
    <match type="string" value="import Qt" offset="0:3000">
      <match type="string" value="{" offset="9:3009"/>
    </match>
    <match type="string" value="import Qml" offset="0:3000">
      <match type="string" value="{" offset="9:3009"/>
    </match>
  </magic>
  <glob pattern="*.qml"/>
  <glob pattern="*.qmltypes"/>
  <glob pattern="*.qmlproject"/>
</mime-type>
```

(notice the `<match type="string" value="import Qt" offset="0:3000">` line, which was probably the one identifying my script as `text/x-qml` since it matched with line 4 of my import statements). I simply deleted that entry from the file, recompiled the MIME database using `sudo update-mime-database -V /usr/share/` and everything went back to normality.